# questions about sums of finite and infinite geometric sequences

Tags: summation

I have been working through some questions in textbook to do with geometric finite and infinite sequences:

The first one is:
${\sum_{i=0}^35^n}$

So I am taking a = 5 and k to be 1 so the equation is:

${5{{1 - (1)^5}\over1-1}}$

But the answer the textbook gives is 156 so I have taken a wrong turn.

Next is

${\sum_{i=0}^\infty 5^n}$

This is undefined but as K is one, I would have thought it is in the range of the absolute value of 1.

Lastly I have:

${\sum_{i=0}^{10}({3\over2})^n}$

So using the formula, I am assuming a = 1 and k = ${3\over2}$:

${1\over{1-{3\over2}}}$

But the answer the book gives is 170.995.

Comment: What are your definitions of $a$  and $k$?

Comment: q=5 not 1 for fiest one. use ^{10}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S_n = a\dfrac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$ for ${\sum_{i=0}^3 5^n}$ we have $S_n = 1\dfrac{1-5^4}{1-5}$.

${\sum_{i=0}^\infty 5^n}$ doesnot convergence since $\lim_{n \to \infty} 5^n=\infty$

$\sum_{i=0}^{10}(\dfrac{3}{2})^n$
$ = 1\dfrac{1-(\dfrac{3}{2})^{11}}{1-\dfrac{3}{2}} $

Comment: $S_n = a\dfrac{1-r^{n\color{#C00000}{+1}}}{1-r}$

Comment: oh, you are right thanks. my mistake

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why number 2 is undefined.  I don't quite understand from  your answer

Comment: For ${\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_n}$ The $ a_n→0 $ is  a necessary(note that not sufficent) condition  to decide the convergence of the series.